# jQuery get request multi-lingual content

Tags: php, jquery

Working on a multilingual site - Danish , German , French , Norway content.

I am facing problems parsing AJAX get requests with multi-lingual content.

```
$.get("scheduler.php?ch_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['chid'] ?>", function (data) {
     console.log(data); // console outputs `nothing` when unable to parse foreign language
});
```

I tried to encode the content in `scheduler.php` :

```
//$name = htmlentities(utf8_encode($name), ENT_QUOTES);
//$name = utf8_encode(htmlentities($name,ENT_NOQUOTES,'utf-8'));
//$name = mb_convert_encoding($name, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
//$name = iconv("windows-1250","UTF-8",$name);
//$name = utf8_encode($name);
```

none of the above encodings work.

Comment: What does the Network tab of Developer Tools (or Dev Console) says about your get request?

Comment: If you choose an encoding (let's say UTF-8) be sure that everything is using the same encoding. So: your PHP / JS / HTML files are saved in UTF-8; in your PHP output UTF-8 in the header: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` before everything else, etc.